# Azure Runbook to make dynamic groups in Azure AD

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-runbook

I am attempting to make an azure runbook to sort Mac computers into two groups based off their processor architecture. To pull the data, I will need to connect to MSGraph and AzureAD. I added the required modules to my runbook. I created an app registration and gave it the proper permissions to read and write in graph along with a client secret to use in the runbook for authentication when I call Connect-MSGraph in the runbook. Since MS Graph does not operate on AAD Groups, I figured I could also connect-AzureAD to manipulate the groups. This is where I am having difficulty. I think I want to use a system-based Managed Identity to call connect-AzureAD, but I am having an issue with this. It was convenient that the Connect-MSGraph cmdlet was capable of using a client secret. I guess my main question is how can I connect to azuread to perform these tasks in this runbook using a system-based Managed Identity? I'll definately be learning with this project. Thanks for any insight offered!

Ill share my Automation Runbook powershell code below:

```
<#
################################
#Connect Azure Managed Identity# this currently does not work!
################################
Write-Output "Connecting to azure via  Connect-AzAccount -Identity" 
Connect-AzAccount -Identity 
Write-Output "Successfully connected with Automation account's Managed Identity" 
Write-Output "Trying to fetch value from key vault using MI. Make sure you have given correct access to Managed Identity" 
$secret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName '<KVname>' -Name '<KeyName>' 

$ssPtr = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($secret.SecretValue) 
try { 
  $secretValueText = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringBSTR($ssPtr) 
    Write-Output $secretValueText 
} finally { 
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ZeroFreeBSTR($ssPtr) 
}

####################################
#End Connect Azure Managed Identity#
####################################
#>

###################
###Main Function###
###################

############################################
##Connect To MS Graph and other Variables ##
############################################
  $tenant = "MYTENANTID"
  #End Editing#
  $authority = "https://login.windows.net/$tenant"
  $AppId = Get-AutomationVariable -Name 'AppId'
  $AppSecret = Get-AutomationVariable -Name 'AppSecret'

  Update-MSGraphEnvironment -AppId $AppId -Quiet
  Update-MSGraphEnvironment -AuthUrl $authority -Quiet
  Connect-MSGraph -ClientSecret $AppSecret -Quiet

#########################
#End connect to MS Graph#
#########################

$Devices = Get-IntuneManagedDevice | Get-MSGraphAllPages | where-Object {$_.OperatingSystem -match "Mac"} | select id, UserPrincipalName, deviceName, managementAgent, azureADDeviceId
foreach ($Device in $Devices){ 
$id = $Device.id 
$DeviceName = $Device.deviceName 
$DeviceOwner = $Device.UserPrincipalName 
$DeviceAgent = $Device.ManagementAgent 
$DeviceIDAzure = $Device.azureADDeviceId 
#"Checking device with id $id, owner $DeviceOwner and name $DeviceName, managed by $DeviceAgent"
if ($DeviceAgent -eq "mdm")
    {
        #"Device managed by intune. Gathering more details"
        $uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/manageddevices('$id')?`$select=hardwareinformation,processorArchitecture"
        $DMS = Invoke-MSGraphRequest -HttpMethod GET -Url $uri
        $CPU = $DMS.processorArchitecture

        #"Device $DeviceName identified with $CPU "
        if ($CPU -eq "x64")
            {
                #"Device identified as intel. Trying to add to intel device group"
                $DeviceObjectID = (Get-AzureADDevice -All:$true | Where-object {$_.DeviceID -match "$DeviceIDAzure"}).ObjectID
                try {
                    Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId "5894c783-c9e8-4808-9fc4-d57110a276a5" -RefObjectId "$DeviceObjectID"
                    "Device $DeviceName added to intel device group"
                }
                catch {
                    "Device $DeviceName already member of intel device group"
                }
            }
        if ($CPU -eq "arM64")
            {
                #"Device identified as M1. Trying to add to M1 device group"
                $DeviceObjectID = (Get-AzureADDevice -All:$true | Where-object {$_.DeviceID -match "$DeviceIDAzure"}).ObjectID
                try {
                    Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId "36955cb4-b5a7-470c-bb0b-7d52061fa825" -RefObjectId "$DeviceObjectID"
                    "Device $DeviceName added to M1 device group"
                }
                catch {
                    "Device $DeviceName already member of M1 device group"
                }
            }
    }
if ($DeviceAgent -eq "jamf")
    {
        "Device $DeviceName managed by JAMF. Not checking more details"
    }
if (($DeviceAgent -ne "mdm") -and ($DeviceAgent -ne "jamf"))
    {
        "Device $DeviceName not managed by inTune or JAMF. Not more details"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, you will not be able to directly connect to Azure AD using system managed identity.

Because when MSI is enabled, a Service Principal object is generated, but the password for that Service Principal is never visible. However, in order to login to Azure AD via Service Principal, you need to use the below command:

> *"Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential "*

and the command requires the service principal's credentials, which we don't have in the case of MSI. That is why we are unable to access the Azure AD   via Managed system identity as discussed briefly in Microsoft [Q & A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/31663/using-a-system-assigned-managed-identity-to-connec).

After a workaround on this, I used [-AadAccessToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/connect-azuread?view=azureadps-2.0#parameters) flag with the `connect-AzureAD` command, generated the token for the `MS graph` and authenticated with the help of token as given below.

```
$Azurecontext = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile.DefaultContext
$gToken = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($Azurecontext.Account, $Azurecontext.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, "https://graph.microsoft.com").AccessToken
$AzureadToken = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($Azurecontext.Account, $Azurecontext.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, "https://graph.windows.net").AccessToken
```

***connect-AzureAD:***

```
Import-Module AzureAD
Connect-AzureAD -AadAccessToken $AzureadToken -AccountId $Azurecontext.Account.Id -TenantId $Azurecontext.tenant.id
```

***Output:***

[image]

Comment: Great this works with connecting to Azure AD. How would I grant this account permissions to manipulate the AAD Groups? I see you can apply RBAC within the subscription, but that does not apply to AAD perms.

Comment: @SophisticatedBear You can create a custom role with the necessary permissions and assign that role to AAD group. For assigning the eligibility of the groups, you can refer this [doc](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/active-directory/privileged-identity-management/groups-assign-member-owner.md) as per the requirement. You can also refer [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/active-directory/roles/custom-group-permissions.md) for more relevant details.